# Rails, correct JSON body for a serialized field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization, ruby-on-rails-4

If I have a Rails model with a serialized field,

```
class Tournament < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :prizes, Array
end
```

and I have the model available through a REST API, what is the correct format of the POST body?

I've tried the following in a Rspec test,

```
post :create, {
    format: :json,
    tournament: {
          prizes: [
            'z2000',
            'z1000',
            'z500',
            'z250'
          ]
    }
}
```

but this results in object with prizes set to blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figure it out. The fix is completely unrelated to my JSON request body.

I had assigned my strong params in my controller as,

```
params.permit(:prizes)
```

But due to it being an array, I need the following

```
params.permit(prizes: [])
```

From https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters,

> To declare that the value in params must be an array of permitted
>   scalar values map the key to an empty array:
>
> params.permit(:id => [])